# Syntax error with awk

Tags: awk

I'm having some problems with syntax using the awk programming language. I tried:

```
$ awk '{if (NR==FNR) a[$2]; else if !($2 in a ) {print $2} }' file1 file2 > file3
```

I got the following error mesages:

```
awk: {if (NR==FNR) a[$2]; else if !($2 in a ) {print $2} }

awk:                              ^ syntax error

awk: {if (NR==FNR) a[$2]; else if !($2 in a ) {print $2} }

awk:                                          ^ syntax error
```

Can somebody help me sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra brackets around the condition:

```
 awk '{if (NR==FNR) a[$2]; else if (!($2 in a )) {print $2} }'
```

Here is the full syntax of the If statement in awk:

```
if (CONDITION) THEN-BODY [else ELSE-BODY]
```

The condition should always be parenthesized

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write your script is:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a){print $2}' file1 file2
```

In `awk` each block of code `{code}` is only executed if the proceeding condition is true. The `next` statement fetches the next line in the input and reruns the script effectively skipping any other blocks.

That is `{a[$2];next}` is executed on `file1` as this is the only time `NR==FNR` and `{print $2}` is only executed when we are reading `file2` and `$2` was found in `file1`.